# C# Load Assembly w/ Common References

Tags: c#, reflection, dll, .net-assembly, system.reflection

I've run into a slight issue - I'm writing a program that loads DLLs, each of which contain a class which inherits from a class existing in a library referenced by both the loaded DLL and the "host" program that is loading the DLL. The issue here is that, when I try to load and cast to the superclass:

```
var assembly = Assembly.LoadFrom(dllPath);
var type = assembly.GetTypes().FirstOrDefault(x => x.IsSubclassOf(typeof (MySuperclass)));
...
```

Although both are referencing the class containing MySuperclass, since the dll is referencing the built class library (a separate file from the class library file the loading program is referencing) IsSubclassOf never returns true, because it considers the two classes to be different as they come from two different assemblies.

Furthermore, if you try casting a created instance of the loaded class to the superclass type, it can't do it since they're not the same (different assemblies).

So, my question is: **how do you handle loading assemblies which reference common code, so that c# recognizes that you're loading a class which inherits from a common superclass?**

Comment: might be a problem with assembly versions, or one of the assembly might be in release and the other in debug, anyway if it's a common library the program and dll should both reference the same dll file

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You simply must use the same assembly files (even if they are identical) if you want programs to work together using common code. Here's how I solved the issue:

The program is loading a DLL from a subdirectory of its own.

Folder structure:

```
MyApp Folder -->
     MyProgram.exe
     CommonDependency.dll
     Submodules ->
         MySubmodule.dll
```

To get MySubmodule to use CommonDependency.dll within the next folder up, it's quite simple. Configure Visual Studio to not copy these dll dependencies to the build folder. Next, create an App.config in Visual Studio and add the following:

```
<configuration>
  <runtime>
    <assemblyBinding>
      <probing privatePath="../"/>
    </assemblyBinding>
  </runtime>
</configuration>
```

This will tell the system to search for the assemblies in the parent folder `../` - if you want to have multiple folders, perhaps a separate dependency folder (relative to the location of the .dll) you can use `;` as the delimiter - `../;../bin/;` - the program will search these locations for the dependencies.

Answer (score -1):

The ancestor class (superclass) must come from the same assembly for any chance for the loading code to work with descendants as a superclass reference.

Comment: As I already said, it comes from the same code, built at the same time.

Comment: It does not matter; the common class library has to be the same executable module, that is the same file.

Comment: Okay, then how do you reference common code if you do not know whether or not you will be loading the same assembly file? For example: http://doc.exitgames.com/photon-server/AnAppFromScratch/ - in this solution, you can see they are referencing .dlls for APIs. The server program then reads these DLLs and can use the code within, since obviously they are not loading from the same assembly, how does one have common code?