# find specific c# class type in dynamically loaded assembly dll

Tags: c#, dll, types, match, .net-assembly

I have a base class...

```
public abstract class PluginBase
{
    ...
}
```

... and I have a derived class...

```
public class Plugin : PluginBase
{
    ...
}
```

... which gets built into `MyDll.dll`.

---

My goal is to create an instance of type `PluginBase` from an implementation found in `MyDll.dll`.

Here is my code.

I load the .dll and loop through each type. I marked the spot where the type check should happen.

```
Assembly a = Assembly.LoadFrom("pathto\MyDll.dll");
foreach (Type t in a.GetTypes())
{
    Boolean isAssignableFrom = /* TODO INSERT TYPE CHECK */
    if (isAssignableFrom)
    {
        PluginBase plugin = (PluginBase) Activator.CreateInstance(t);
        plugin.Initialize();
    }
}
```

---

The problem is that I cannot get it to match the type found in the loaded .dll with the "same" type in the solution i start the project from.

Here is a snipped from the debugger regarding the "correct" type and the loaded one:

```
+ t {Name = "Plugin" FullName = "...plugins.MyPlugin.Plugin"}   System.Type {System.RuntimeType}
+ t.BaseType    {Name = "PluginBase" FullName = "...Plugin.PluginBase"} System.Type {System.RuntimeType}
+ typeof(PluginBase)    {Name = "PluginBase" FullName = "...Plugin.PluginBase"} System.Type {System.RuntimeType}
```

As you can see, the type found in the assembly (Variable `t`) has `PluginBase` as the `.BaseType` .

I tried the following equality checks, all of which returned `false` as the result.

```
+ t is PluginBase
+ t == typeof(PluginBase)
+ typeof(PluginBase).IsAssignableFrom(t)
+ t.BaseType is PluginBase
+ t.BaseType == typeof(PluginBase)
+ typeof(PluginBase).IsAssignableFrom(t.BaseType)
```

If I ignore the check and try to create an instance instead I get a followup error when I try to cast it, the exception message goes is as follows:

> System.InvalidCastException: 'Unable to cast object of type
>   '...plugins.MyPlugin.Plugin' to type '...Plugin.PluginBase'.'

A cast, which in my opinion should work.

I also cleaned the whole solution and rebuilt everything, because I thought the reason might be an outdated .dll or something like that - it didn't help.

What am I missing?

Comment: Make sure you don't accidentally have two separate versions of `PluginBase`. Can happen if you include the source file into both projects instead of just referencing. The `AssemblyQualifiedName` should help with this.

Comment: @Jester I checked the `AssemblyQualifiedName` for the .dll type and the solution type:

`+ t.BaseType.AssemblyQualifiedName "...Plugin.PluginBase, ...Plugin, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null"` and 
`+ typeof(PluginBase).AssemblyQualifiedName "...Plugin.PluginBase, ...Plugin, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null"`

They are asbsolutely identical.

I haven't included the source in both projects, they are just referencing the `ProjectBase` project.

Also, this doesn't help to create an instance of the type

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Alright I managed to find the solution in [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16492312/6459948). Although I checked other posts before asking my question I still didn't come across this one.

Nevertheless, the solution is to work with the same .dll.

**Although the .dll files are identical, the program thinks it's different because it's not in the same location.**

For this to work, I just deleted the .dll file of the base class in the build directory of the derived class.

For me, this solved both problems. The one with matching the types and creating an instance.